# Can't choose any category in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, category, category-tree, magento-1.9.4.0

I can't choose any **category** in the admin panel for editing. You will always see the creation of a new category.

`Magento 1.9.4.0` clean setup,

`mariaDB 10.3`,

`php 7.1.25`,

`CentOS`.

Comment: additional: Web panel - vestaCP, web server - nginx

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1.x.x doesn't support php7.1. You should check Magento 1 system requirement [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html)

Did you add a custom module to fix this? Maybe [this article](https://inchoo.net/magento/its-alive/) can help you

Comment: Magento 1.9.4.0 support php 7.2
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1940

Comment: But you are using php 7.1.25? Could you please check there is any issue in var/log folder? exception.log and system.log ? Make sure you've already enabled it in System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes